# @Html.DisplayFor does not show property of strongly typed ListObject which is a property of model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am having my model as `ClassA` below :

```
public class ClassA{
public List<ClassB> bs {get;set}

}
```

while `ClassB`:

```
public class ClassB {
public Datetime? date{get;set;}

}
```

I am trying to iterate over this class in the following manner in my view

```
@model ClassA
...

@foreach(var b in @Model.bs)
{
var _index = 0;
 @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.bs.ElementAt(_index).date)
_index++;
}
```

but i am getting a blank text in my view even though there is data. 
All i want to do is print this data after iterating over the list.Since,DisplayFor by default takes only the model i can't use `bs` in the `DisplayFor` helper directly.

Please provide sample code how to achieve the desired result.

Comment: `@foreach(var b in @Model.bs) { @Html.DisplayFor(x => b.date)  }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke simple and works!!

Comment: @StephenMuecke you should submit this as an answer so it can be accepted

Answer (score 0):

```
 var _index = 0;   
 @foreach(var b in @Model.bs)
    {

         @Html.DisplayFor(x => @Model.bs.ElementAt(_index).date)
         _index++;
    }
```